# IllegalStateException in android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader

Tags: android, illegalstateexception

Please help me figure this out. I just got this from developer console android vitals. I dont know how to reproduce the crash. I just want to know why it is happening or how can I fix it if possible.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:612)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication (ActivityThread.java:4673)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500 (ActivityThread.java:162)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1409)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:135)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5422)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:372)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:914)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:707)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
  at android.app.LoadedApk.initializeJavaContextClassLoader (LoadedApk.java:458)
  at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication (LoadedApk.java:604)
```

Comment: FrickzzZ, have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I also got a crash report with this error for the following device: `Vodafone Smart_Tab_3G (Vodafone_Smart_Tab_3G), 512MB RAM, Android 4.4`